# Django-admin: How to display related objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Assume I have got an employee class, and I want to have an inline form that showing all other employee objects that share the same first_name with current object. How to do this inline form?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [inline formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).